# Defuse... It's going to blast!

Tags: cipher, visual

You are an intelligent decoder. The FBI now needs your help to defuse a bomb. You move near it and find the following notes.

[image]

[image]

> You have a glance at the notes. You are now ready to decode and defuse..  The bomb has a key pad with some characters.
>
> ## What should you enter to defuse the bomb ???

[image]

Comment: I feel like the words correspond to cardinal directions - Up, Down, Left, Right, Forward, Back. I don't know how to translate those three-dimensional directions onto a two-dimensional keypad, though.

Comment: Yes, they are. Think about the cases where we encounter these directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Athin did the hard work with his [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/85816/60239).

> 1. A rubics pattern named "four crosses "
>  2. A rubics pattern named "Don't cross line"

So, what does the hints tell us?

> Crosses may help you: Pattern 1 could be the key
>  If you cross the line, bomb explodes: ok, dont cross the line. Pattern 2 would kill us.

Lets try it

> I would not enter the pattern itself. I would enter four crosses: **XXXX**

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure they are indicating

> Rubik's notation, looking at their initials

which is

> 1. U2 R2 L2 F2 B2 D2 L2 R2 F2 B2
>  2. F2 L2 R2 B2 E2

So we have these:

> **First moves**
>
>  [image]
>
>  **Second moves**
>
>  [image]
>
>  **(First+Second moves)**
>
>  [image]

Now,

> It's a bit broad what should I enter to defuse the bomb. Maybe solving the cube?
>  In that case, just **reverse the rotations** (going back to front).

Comment: Yes almost complete... These patterns(the first and second) have certain names, those names will help you.

Comment: rot13(Gur svefg bar vf pnyyrq "4 pebffrf" , gur frpbaq bar vf pnyyrq "Qba'g pebff yvar"
Fb gur uvagf va gur dhrfgvba znxr frafr abj)

Comment: @Bananenkopp nice observation! But I'm still not sure what to enter in the end...

Comment: rot13(V jbhyq vachg "S2 Y2 E2 O2 R2" (Svther 2) juvpu zrnaf "Qba'g pebff gur yvar" orpnhfr uvag fnlf "Vs lbh pebff vg, obzo rkcybqrf" naq jr qbag jnag gung.)

Answer (score 1):

We would enter

> ! the first letter on the notes. That is UURRLLFFBBDDLLRRFFBB, then for next line FFLLRRBBEE. I am entering twice because of the exponent power 
>   Edit: May be total answer would be 1'UURRLLFFBBDDLLRRFFBB2'FFLLRRBBEE

Comment: This feels way too simple to be the answer...

Comment: I am new and dont know how things work here. I was taught that no matter how complex something is always try the simplest way(correct of course)

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it's worth a shot.

Comment: There’s no harm in trying the first guess that comes to mind—except when you’re, say, defusing a bomb...

Comment: @ValAsta You're almost near....

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the numbers in front of the clues. Maybe — seeing what @ValAsta said — you could type:

> 1UURRLLFFBBDDLLRRFFBB then 2FFLLRRBBEE